# Match a unicode character class using Apps script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to change the font family of Hebrew characters using Google Apps Script.

I get the error

> Invalid regular expression pattern [\u0590-\u05fe]

I have tried with

```
        var searchExp = "[\u0590-\u05fe]";
        var searchResult = body.findText(searchExp);
        while (searchResult !== null) {
            var thisElement = searchResult.getElement();
            var thisElementText = thisElement.asText();
            thisElementText.setFontFamily(searchResult.getStartOffset(), searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(), "Arial");
            // search for next match
            searchResult = body.findText(searchExp, searchResult);
        }
```

The findText methods used are [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String)) and [this one](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern-from)

Comment: It works on my side as expected, it sets the Hebrew text font to Arial. I even tried with `var searchExp = "[\\x{0590}-\\x{05fe}]";` with the same result.

Comment: You need to double escape. ```\\```